# SQL Server : report TOP queries by total CPU time

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage

SQL Server report - **TOP queries by total CPU time** returns the same query for top 10 high CPU consuming queries.

```
 SELECT SUM(db.buffer_pool_size) AS instance_buffer_pool_size 
 FROM (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) * (8*1024) AS buffer_pool_size 
       FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors WITH (nolock) 
       WHERE database_id <> 32767   -- ResourceDB 
       GROUP BY database_id) db
```

This query is being executed on all databases present on the SQL Server.

We have searched for all views, functions, procedures, SQL job steps and did not find anything from where this query is being executed.

Any suggestions for how to check from where it is being executed?

Comment: Use a Profiler or extended event sessions to capture the execution of this query specifically, and include any detail necessary in the event (originating IP, session, account name, etc.) to narrow down where it's coming from.

Comment: I would go for Profiler too, but you have to wait for the query to run. Maybe you can search part of the query (like table names or columns) in your database objects and narrow the search. This can help: SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%%'. Also you can use the stored proc sp_depends to search for such dependencies.

Comment: I have checked and found that query is being executed from the server itself. The only new thing we have done on the server was installing new relic agent and after disabling query stopped executing. Thanks for your help guys!!! CHEERS